# How to avoid duplicated class definitions in JS

Tags: javascript, class, oop

I declared a class in my script as following;

```
class XYPT {
constructor(x, y) {
this.x = x;
this.y = y;
}
}
```

For some reasons, I have to load this script several times with jquery getscript method. When I try to define this class, it gives me an error 'Identifier 'XYPT' has already been declared'.

Is it possible to check if a class is declared before? I'm looking for something like this,

```
(isDeclaredBefore(XYPT))
{
//do nothing
}
else
{
  class XYPT {
    constructor(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;}
  }
}
```

Comment: If your intent is to ignore the updated definition of the class, why reload it at all?  Seems like you could solve the problem by not reloading this code with getScript.

Comment: My script does lots of things with this class. By the way, my script is working as intended, I just dont feel good when I see this warning in console.

Comment: you have to refresh the page and go over. I think you're using chrome console!

Comment: @BloodyLogic I didn't understand your suggestion. In which way it can help me?

I have a script which works everytime a data changes. It works exactly the way I want it to work. It's just I want to define class once, and avoid it on other runs.

Comment: which editor do you use?  it happens on google snippets, once you wrote you code and execute it then come to console for testing, don't change the snippet direct, if you do, you have to refresh the page then it'll work!

Answer (score 3):

Your question is reasonable.

Everyone should first **organize there code and imports** to prevent class re-declaration  but in some rare case you can check for class existence before declaration.

Has suggested @Eldar, we will be using `class expression`, but his example is not the simplest to understand.

```
if (typeof window.MyClassFooBar === 'undefined') {
    window.MyClassFooBar = class {
        constructor(settings) {
             this.settings = settings;
        }

        doStuff() {
             /* ... */
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: This is genious! Basically C's #ifndef .. #define approach. I have a single-page app which dynamically loads parts of it depending on which section the user is, so it happens that code is loaded over and over every time the section is entered. Not sure whether this is the best architecture - currently I don't want to have the whole app in the browser at once. May I'll change that but for now, your solution helps ;-)

Answer (score 0):

you can check if the class is already defined like this.

```js
class foo {

}

// check it, if it is defined
if ( typeof foo === 'function' ) 
{
  console.log('defined'); // write you logic here
}
else 
 {
   // otherwise, something here
   console.log('not')
 } 
  
  

let per = new foo();
```

I hope you got some idea!

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. With this reply, I learned how to check if a class is defined. But I realized that it doesn't help me at all. If I do the null check before class declaration. It gives me a warning about it. If I check after declaration, I still redeclare it. Therefore, either way I get a warning.

Comment: I encounter the issue both on localhost and deployed versions. What is the difference?

Comment: create your class once and use everywhere or extend it, but don't declare twice. if you do, create by different name!

Answer (score 0):

You can put use the class expression in ecmascript 2015 as mentioned [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/class)

```js
class foo {
    constructor(x, y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
if (typeof foo === "function") {
    var bar = class { // this is another way of defining classes but otherwise it won't work
        constructor(y) {
            this.y = y;
        }
    };
}
if (typeof bar === "function") {
    var baz = class {
        constructor(z) {
            this.z = z;
        }
    };
}
if (typeof baz === "function") {
    var b2 = new baz(13);
    console.log(b2.z);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured that best way to avoid redeclaration of a class is to exclude it from the repeating script file, and declare it in another script which called before the repeating script.